# Assigning values to an array, values not kept?

Tags: qt, qml

I can assign values to a variable property but not to an array here?  ... values aren't kept.

```
Column {
     id: table

     property variant aa: [false, false] //issue... later
     property variant bb: false //this works

     ...

     Button {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0//40
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 0//50
        corpFarmAware: true
        text: tr_NOOP("Next")

        onClicked: {
            table.aa[0] = false;
            table.aa[1] = true;
            cb0.checked = table.aa[0];//issue of arrays ??
            cb1.checked = table.aa[1];

            table.bb = true;
            cb2.checked = table.bb;//WORKS
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation on [variant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-variant.html#storing-arrays-and-objects) in QML:

> While this is a convenient way to store array and map-type values, you must be aware that the items and attributes properties above are not QML objects (and certainly not JavaScript object either) and the key-value pairs in attributes are not QML properties. Rather, the items property holds an array of values, and attributes holds a set of key-value pairs. Since they are stored as a set of values, instead of as an object, **their contents cannot be modified individually**

I think you should use [var](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qml-var.html) to store your properties.